# Change html in woocommerce product without was now save prices

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

So i have products at the store that have was now and save prices with custom html.
Now i need to change product price without those attributes, that have only single price(regular price).

Problem is they have the same class and for some reason when i change html only the was-now-save class get's changed but the product with regular price do not.

```php
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bbloomer_simple_product_price_format', 10, 2 );

   function bbloomer_simple_product_price_format( $price, $product ) {

       $str = "Ušteda:";
       if ( $product->is_on_sale() && $product->is_type('simple') ) {
           $price = sprintf( __( '<div class="was-now-save"><ul>
           <li>
           <div class="was">
           <span class="text">MP cena:</span>%1$s</div>
           </li><li><div class="save"><span class="text">' . $str . '</span>%3$s</div></li></li><div class="now"><span class="text">Cena:</span>%2$s</div></li></ul></div>', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price ( $product->get_regular_price() ), wc_price( $product->get_sale_price() ), wc_price( $product->get_regular_price() - $product->get_sale_price() )  );        
       }

       return $price;
   }
```

Comment: send screenshots .

Comment: https://ibb.co/kHYpbwP

Comment: I mean can you please let us know your issue with screenshot what exactly are you looking for ?

Comment: As i said these two are the same class, i cant add custom html to the first one, only the second